# SQL Need to restrict the result of openquery based on column value database

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I am using the below open query to fetch the data from the linked server

```
select * from openquery(HH2, 'select * from "!Root"."!All".RAWDATA' )
WHERE quality = 0 and TAGNAME LIKE '%OBTS_data%' AND TIMESTAMP <= '2022-10-10 13:27'
```

I need to restrict it with the respect to the database values
means that once all the items from the database value are available in one column the query should stop executing.

Query output is like [image]

The database looks like

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `OPENQUERY` why not just a normal linked server query `select * from HH2.[!Root].[!All].RAWDATA WHERE quality = 0 and TAGNAME LIKE '%OBTS_data%' AND TIMESTAMP <= '2022-10-10 13:27'` Your actual question is unclear: What condition are you trying to enforce, when should the query "stop executing"? And please do not post images of code or data, we need to see sample data and expected results *as text*.

Comment: What does "*once all the items from the database value are available in one column the query should stop executing*" mean?

Comment: Thanks for the response I need this query to fetch only one data per line item i.e. i am expecting only one result per tagname
Or
The query stops execution as soon as the result has all the tagnames from the DB atleast once

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to rewrite the query with some other function example as below

USE Alarm
DECLARE @Tag nVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Tagname FROM OBTS_Tags
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Tag
DROP TABLE T1
create table T1
(
TAGNAME nVarchar(100),
TIMESTAMP datetime,
QUALITY VARCHAR(50),
VALUE Bit
)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @tag
DECLARE  @SQL as nVarchar(max),
@Time as varchar(max),
@LinkedServer varchar(100),
@FSQL as nVarchar(max),
@TSQL NVARCHAR(1000);

```
        SET @Time = '2022-10-13 13:27'
        SET @LinkedServer = 'HH2'
        SET @SQL =  'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
        SET @TSQL = 'select * from "!Root"."!All".RAWDATA WHERE quality = 0 and TAGNAME = '''''+@Tag+''''' AND TIMESTAMP <= '''''+@Time+''''''')';
        SET @FSQL = '('+(@SQL+@TSQL)+') ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC'
```

PRINT @FSQL

INSERT INTO T1
EXEC (@FSQL)

```
   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Tag
```

END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor